# Convert raw image into a known raw image format

Tags: image, image-processing, photo

I have captured some raw images from a Sony sensor (not a Sony camera, but a Sony sensor) and I would like to edit/demosaic the photo in raw format. (file extension is .raw)

The problem: Since the image was not captured by a consumer camera on the market, the raw file format is not supported by most photo editing software.

I have a program that could convert the raw file I captured into tiff format, however I want to open the raw file in a photo editor like PhotoShop or DxO.

Is there a software tool that could help convert an unknown raw format into a known raw format? (Something like a .dng file) I tried looking for one, but no luck :(

If not, would it be hard to make a program that can achieve this? What programming language will be best for the job, and which raw format is simpler to convert to?

---

I am guessing the raw capture simply has a empty header with no metadata/exif, so maybe if I can copy a header from a given raw format and tweak the dimensions etc, perhaps it will work.
This is just a very random guess, but I doubt it will work since I am not knowledgeable on this subject.

Any help is appreciated!

---

2014/08/11 edit:

I was able to open the raw file in PhotoShop and imageJ now. (I filled in the correct dimension of the image and channels, header length etc..) It is opened as a Grey scale Bayer raw image.

This didn't help much as I want to de-mosaic it with software such as DxO or Raw Therapee, so is there a way I could save my Grey scale Bayer image into a raw format recognized by these editing software? (For DxO it is hard as it needs to know the camera model of the raw file, which means I need to copy a header from a camera created raw file. The problem is I don't even know where to start in terms of a tool that can do this.)

Currently what I know about the raw file:
Size, Dimension, Channels, Header size, Bayer pattern, Endian, and Color Depth.

Comment: Photoshop opens TIFF files. Does that not work for you?

Comment: Sorry I wasnt clear on that, I wanted to be able to open the raw image file and let the image editor demosaic the Bayer raw image. The ".raw" I have now cannot be opened by editor such as DxO since it is a unknown file type (or empty header)

Comment: This is going to be tough if you don't even know the orientation of the Bayer filter.

Answer (score 0):

I converted raw images with a GStreamer script:

```
#!/bin/sh

FILESIZE=1382400
FRAME_DIMS=width=1280,height=720

echo converting $1

gst-launch-1.0 -v filesrc location=$1 blocksize=$FILESIZE ! \
        video/x-raw,format=NV12,$FRAME_DIMS,framerate=1/1 ! \
        videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=RGB,framerate=1/1 ! \
        pngenc ! \
        filesink location=$1.png
```

Comment: Where did you get those magic numbers? 1382400 etc

Comment: Not sure now, perhaps it was the original file size.